# Вывод значения из javascript файла в консоль веб сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня сервер на node js:`

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
     res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body> <button onclick="var test = prompt("Enter a number");"></button> </body>
</html>
`);
}).listen(3000, () => console.log('Server work'));`
```

Как вывести в консоль запущенного сервера эту переменную которую и предлогалось ввести пользователю (переменная test в html коде)?

Comment: запрос на сервер отправлять надо

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо отправить запрос на сервер и там его обработать:

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (~req.url.indexOf('/test')) {
        console.log(decodeURIComponent(req.url.split('/test/').pop()));
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html><html><body> 
          <button onclick="fetch('/test/' + encodeURIComponent(prompt('Enter a number')));">test</button> 
          </body></html>
        `);
    }
}).listen(3000, () => console.log('Server work'));
```